# How can i use laravel mix with an apache alias?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I have configured my app to be available under an alias (http://localhost/myapp). How can i configure mix to reflect this in the manifest file? I want to reference `/myapp/css/app.css` instead of `/css/app.css`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it, read the docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#url-processing

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/app/app.scss', 'public/css')
.options({
   processCssUrls: false
});
```